# Changing IMG SRC with Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, image, src

I'm new at javascript and while there are many more complex solutions, I don't understand them and hope I don't have to at this point.

I have a main picture...

```
<img src="main-picture.jpg" name="Mainpic" id="image">
```

...and I want to be able to change this picture when I click on one of two thumbnails.

```
<a href="" onclick="FirstPic()"><img src="replacement1.jpg" name="pic1"></a>
<a href="" onclick="SecPic()"><img src="replacement2.jpg" name="pic2"></a>
```

My javascript code I thought would be super easy.  I'm currently using...

```
function FirstPic(){
        document.Mainpic.src = document.pic1.src
        return
    }

function SecPic(){
        document.Mainpic.src = document.pic2.src
        return
    }
```

Now the variable **is** changing however it's not **staying** changed.  When the thumbnail is clicked on, the replacement picture flashes on the screen and then it returns to the original main-picture.jpg.

How do I make the change permanent until a different thumbnail is clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's flipping back because your page is reloading.

You need to return false from your onclick= if you don't want the href= value to activate after your onclick.

Also, you can set href="#" just in case. # goes nowhere (doesn't ever reload the page)

Comment: On other note, I think you can do away with link tag and write the click event on the image itself.

Comment: JasonWoof, that worked perfect, thanks.  However Biswanath's answer worked perfect too and was more efficient so I just got rid of the link tag altogether.

Comment: Adding # will make it scroll to the top of the page, if the page is scrollable, and add a step in the history list. So you really need to return false from the handler `<a href="#" onclick="FirstPic(); return false">`

Answer (score 0):

I think your page is refreshing by your click, change your links as :

```
<a href="" onclick="FirstPic(); return false;"><img src="replacement1.jpg" name="pic1"></a>
<a href="" onclick="SecPic(); return false;"><img src="replacement2.jpg" name="pic2"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this (haven't checked the syntax completly, so it could be faulty.

```
function FirstPic()
{
    var pic1 = document.getElementById("pic1"); 
    if (pic1 == typeof('undefined')) return;
    pic1.src = "newpicname.jpg";
}
```

Make sure you give the  tags an ID attribute called pic1 and pic2 (instead of a name attribute) and give the image itself an 'onclick' attribute...

```
<img onclick='FirstPic()' id='pic1' src='image1.jpg' />
```