# load the src of an image from .js file?

Tags: javascript

I have a file called `src.js` which has all the scripts for my html page.

Now on my HTML page I am using this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="src.js">
</script>
```

Now what I want to have an image in my html file (`<img src=""/>`) and the src of that image I want to load form the `.js` file.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JS file you can select the image element and update it's source:

```
document.getElementById('image-id').src = '/path/to/image.jpg';
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<img id="image-id" src="/images/blank-pixel.png" />
```

It is important to set the source of the image to something so the browser doesn't load unnecessary assets looking for a source that doesn't exist.

You can also store the path to the image in a data-attribute on the image tag itself and load it from JavaScript:

JS--

```
var image = document.getElementById('image-id');
image.src = image.getAttribute('data-src');
```

HTML--

```
<img id="image-id" data-src="/path/to/image.jpg" src="/images/blank-pixel.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this :
[Changing IMG SRC with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395990/changing-img-src-with-javascript) ?

If yes, then read that question and read the answers
It may helps you